# Android. Неявный Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Вот [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/intents-filters.html) написано: "При вызове метода startActivity() система анализирует все установленные приложения, чтобы определить, какие из них могут откликнуться на объект Intent этого вида.... ....Если объект Intent принимают несколько операций, система отображает диалоговое окно, в котором пользователь может выбрать приложение для выполнения данного действия."

Возник вопрос - можно ли исключить из диалогового окна конкретное приложение, если оно установлено у пользователя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант кастомизировать выбор приложения.

Получить список

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
videoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("url"), "video/*");
List<ResolveInfo> video = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(videoIntent, 0);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ResolveInfo info : video){
    if(!info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("packageName")){
        list.add(info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
    }
}
```

Предложить выбор

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select");
builder.setItems(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       //...
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Comment: Подойдёт! Спасибо